# How to use C++ function from header in C?

Tags: c++, c, header, program-entry-point

I'm writing my thesis and I have problem with using C++ function in C code. I searched solution and I found a lot of them, but it didn't work anyway. Please explain it to me one more time.

To be quick I have something like below and after `gcc main.c -o main` I get `undefined reference to 'cppfun'`

**cpp.h:**

```
#pragma once

#ifdef __cplusplus
 extern "C" {
#endi

    void cppfun();

#ifdef __cplusplus
 }
#endif
```

**cpp.cpp:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cpp.h"

void cppfun()
{
    printf("cpp_fun");
}
```

**main.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#indlude "cpp.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cppfun();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you combine C and C++, you should compile the translation unit containing the `main` function, as C++. Not opposite. This is [a FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp#overview-mixing-langs).

An undefined reference is usually because you haven't linked in the translation unit where the missing thing is. Your stated build command is

> ```
> gcc main.c -o main
> ```

while it should be e.g.

```
gcc -c main.c
g++ -c cpp.cpp
g++ cpp.o main.o -o main
```

except as mentioned, the main translation unit should be in C++.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include all .cpp files after main. Something like that:

```
g++ main.cpp other.cpp etc.cpp -o main
```

Comment: This worked too and I have more files in cpp, this one command do it all, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you compile your cpp code **without link** via **-c** compiler switch

g++ cpp.cpp -c

and you have cpp.o file then compile and link your main.c with cpp.h and cpp.o files via gcc

gcc main.c -o main cpp.o

I tested this answer via my linux server. It is work.

[image]